# Delete from MySQL DB, Form does't get displayed in PHP

Tags: php, html, css, bootstrap-4

I dont know what iam doing wrong, but my form doesn't get displayed.

Here's the code :

PostDelete.php:

```html
<?php

session_start();

$username=$_SESSION['uname'];

// Process delete operation after confirmation
if(isset($_POST["pid"]) && !empty($_POST["pid"])){

    $cn=mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "imedtalks");
    
    // Prepare a delete statement
    $sql = "DELETE FROM posts WHERE pid = ?";
    
    if($stmt = mysqli_prepare($cn, $sql)){
        // Bind variables to the prepared statement as parameters
        mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, "i", $param_pid);
        
        // Set parameters
        $param_pid = trim($_POST["pid"]);
        
        // Attempt to execute the prepared statement
        if(mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt)){
            // Records deleted successfully. Redirect to landing page
            header("location: CAposts.php");
            exit();
        } else{
            echo "Oops! Something went wrong. Please try again later.";
        }
    }
     
    // Close statement
    mysqli_stmt_close($stmt);
    
    // Close connection
    mysqli_close($cn);
} else{
    // Check existence of id parameter
    if(empty(trim($_GET["pid"]))){
        // URL doesn't contain id parameter. Redirect to error page
        header("location: CAposts.php");
        exit();
    }
}
?>




  <html>

  <head>
    <title>Delete PostID-
      <?php echo $_GET["pid"];?>
    </title>

    <link href="./css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <script src="./scripts/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="./scripts/bootstrap.min.js"></script>


    <style>
      
      .wrapper {
        width: 500px;
        margin: 0 auto;
      }
    </style>

  </head>

  <body>


    <div class="wrapper">
      <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-md-12">
            <div class="page-header">
              <h1 class="text-center">Delete Post</h1>
            </div>
            <form action="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]); ?>" method="POST">
              <div class="alert alert-danger fade">
                <input type="hidden" name="pid" value="<?php echo trim($_GET[" pid "]); ?>"/>
                <div>Are you sure you want to delete this record?</div><br>
                <div>
                  <button type="submit" name="yes" class="btn btn-danger">Yes</button>
                  <a href="CAposts.php"><button type="button" name="no" class="btn btn-primary">No</button></a>
                </div>
              </div>
            </form>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

  </body>

  </html>
```

Here, in i am trying to delete a row, using the pid, which is retrieved from the url i.e. passed from the previous page.

I just want to display a alert, on the user choice, if yes button is pressed, the page is called again, to execute the sql query.

But, i don't know why, but just the heading, 'Delete Post' is getting showed up there, and the form gets skipped.

I am using Bootstrap 4 here.

Comment: Does your server show you errors?  `<?php echo $_GET["pid"];?>` will generate a warning because it is not set.

Comment: no, it does not show any error, and it works, the pid gets displayed.

Comment: what does the source listing show you?

Answer (score 1):

Its because you haven't initialized the variable before use.

Put this statement:

`$param_pid = trim($_POST["pid"]);`

Before:

`mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, "i", $param_pid);`

Comment: It was working fine without error, but i tried your way too, it does not affects the result output though.
Its still the same, only till the h1 tag from the html part gets displayed, don't know, but the form is still missing.

Comment: Please try to debug things. Print `$_POST['pid]`, print SQL, print sql results, etc... It should work. Its not a big deal if you debug the code.